# Getting earliest transaction records where a transaction code 12 occurs after a code 3, for each customer in my list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a customer transaction table with columns ***customer_number, transaction_date, transaction_code, transaction_amount*** and a few other columns.

For each customer_number in my predefined list (let's say 1,2,3,4), I want to get the earliest transactions where a code 12 transaction_code occurs after a code 3 transaction_code. So for example, if customer 1 had a transaction code 12 which occurred anytime after a transaction code 3, I would want to get both the transaction rows for customer 1 (the earliest transaction 12, and the earliest transaction 3 which occurs before it). Same for any other customers in my list that have a transaction code 12 occurring after a transaction code 3.

Here is what I have so far. I know why it doesn't work but I can't figure out how to make it get what I want. The below code checks if the transaction code 12 date is greater than the minimum of **all** transaction code 3 dates, not just for each particular customer_number.

```
SELECT t1.* from trans_table t1
WHERE t1.transaction_date > 
(select min(t2.transaction_date) 
from trans_table t2
WHERE t2.customer_number= t1.customer_number
AND t2.transaction_code = 3 
)
AND t1.transaction_code = 12
AND t1.customer_number in (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: What does `SELECT @@version;` return?

Comment: @BillKarwin Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4583465) - 11.0.7507.2 (X64)   Nov  1 2020 00:48:37   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )

Comment: I have removed the 'mysql' tag. MySQL and Microsoft SQL Server are different products, and a solution for one may not be a solution for the other. Please pay attention to your tags and tag your questions accurately. It helps you because it will attract the attention of people most likely to answer your question.

Comment: Sample data and desired results (as tabular tex) would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty solution that might work:

```sql
DECLARE @data TABLE ( customer_number int, transaction_date date, transaction_code int, transaction_amount numeric(9,2))

INSERT INTO @data
VALUES  (1, '20221231', 1, 10)
,   (1, '20230101', 1, 10)
,   (1, '20230102', 3, 100)
,   (1, '20230104', 4, 100)
,   (1, '20230105', 12, 100)
,   (1, '20230202', 3, 100)

,   (2, '20230101', 12, 10)
,   (2, '20230102', 3, 100)
,   (2, '20230105', 12, 100)
,   (2, '20230202', 3, 100)

,   (3, '20230101', 12, 10)
,   (3, '20230102', 12, 10)
,   (3, '20230103', 3, 100)

,   (4, '20230101', 3, 10)
,   (4, '20230102', 3, 10)
,   (4, '20230103', 12, 100)

,   (5, '20230101', 3, 10)
,   (5, '20230102', 12, 10)
,   (5, '20230103', 3, 100)
,   (5, '20230104', 12, 100)

SELECT  TOP 1 WITH ties * -- 4
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    ,   COUNT(*) OVER(partition BY customer_number, totalFlag) AS numberOfRecords -- 3
    FROM    (
            SELECT  sum(flag) OVER(partition BY customer_number ORDER BY transaction_date) AS totalFlag -- 2
            ,   *
            FROM    (
                SELECT  CASE WHEN lag(transaction_code) OVER(partition BY customer_number ORDER BY transaction_code) = 3 AND transaction_code = 12 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END flag -- 1
                ,   *
                FROM    @data
                WHERE   transaction_code IN (3,12)
            ) x
        ) x
    ) x
WHERE   x.numberOfRecords > 1
ORDER BY dense_rank() OVER(partition BY customer_number ORDER BY totalFlag) -- 5
```

The idea is to use a gaps and island style of query to group the transactions together by "flag". This flag is increased every time a number combination of transactions occurs.

The details here:

1. This creates a flag which gets value 0 for desirable combo, and 1 for undesirable one. This allows us to increase the flag when we break a correct combo. So first row (3) will get flag = 1, and second row that matches (12) will keep flag = 1 meaning we get a desirable group.
2. This summarize the above flag creating a running sum and creates a grouping column
3. This counts the number of rows in our combination. This is needed because otherwise we might get only "3" as transaction combination, here we want to have 2 rows ("3" and "12")
4. and 5. With ties is a little trick which returns all first rows, regardless of how many customers we get. The DENSE_RANK creates another counter which calculates the first "correct" transaction combination

It's a bit involved query, but avoids some other complicated things, so maybe it will work out for you

Comment: Hi @siggemannen. God idea. I think, ``lag(transaction_code)`` takes ``nearest before`` (not first) row with code=3. Pls, check this point.

Comment: @siggemannen thanks for your response. Is there a way to do it where you can specify the customer_numbers instead of assuming it's customers 1-4 sequentially?

Comment: Add a where customer_number IN (1, 2, 5, 10) somewhere in the query ? Or maybe you mean something else?

Comment: @siggemannen yep, what you said. Add a where customer_number IN (1, 2, 5, 10)